# ruby regexp find the pattern more than once

Tags: ruby, regex, string

```
value = "Men - $30, Women - $20"
# value = "Men - 0"
# value = "free"
data = /\$(\d*)/.match value
```

Currently:

```
data.to_a
 => ["$30", "30"]
```

I want:

```
data.to_a
 => ["$30", "30", "$20", "20]
```

How to accomplish that

Comment: just enable the global `g` modifier.

Comment: That is: unknown regexp option - g

Comment: If you don’t need repetitions, here you go: `"Men - $30, Women - $20".scan(/\$(\d*)/)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan)

```
value = "Men - $30, Women - $20"

value.scan(/(\$(\d+))/)
# => [["$30", "30"], ["$20", "20"]]

value.scan(/(\$(\d+))/).flatten
# => ["$30", "30", "$20", "20"]
```

Comment: Short and sweet, I like the `flatten` :) +1